# OpenFaaS : Receiving Timeout errors during health check of function Pod

Tags: health-check, kubernetes-health-check, openfaas

**Issue:**

We have added health check configuration to our function. However pod becomes Unhealthy due to timeout error in liveness and readiness checks and consequently getting restarted.
**However if I hit same health check url using CURL or browser it returns correct response.**

Health check [configuration reference](https://docs.openfaas.com/reference/workloads/#custom-http-health-check).

We are using **Kubernetes HPAv2** for auto-scaling ([Reference](https://docs.openfaas.com/tutorials/kubernetes-hpa/)).

**test-function.yml**

```
  test-function:
    lang: quarkus-java-with-fonts
    handler: ./test-function
    image: repo.azurecr.io/test-function:0.1
    labels:
      agentpool: openfaas
      com.openfaas.scale.min: "2"
      com.openfaas.scale.max: "10"
      com.openfaas.scale.factor: 0
    annotations:
     com.openfaas.health.http.path: "/health"
     com.openfaas.health.http.initialDelay: "30s"
    environment:
        secret_name: environment-variables
    secrets:
        - environment-variables 
    constraints:
        - agentpool=openfaas
    limits:
      cpu: 1500m
      memory: 1Gi
    requests:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 500Mi
```

**Error Trace :**

```
Liveness probe failed: Get "http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:8080/health": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Readiness probe failed: Get "http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:8080/health": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Any idea what could be wrong.

Comment: Mikołaj Głodziak has already provided a valid answer. Was it useful ? If yes, Please upvote or accept the answer for greater visibility to community members.

Answer (score 1):

These errors:

```yaml
Liveness probe failed: Get "http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:8080/health": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Readiness probe failed: Get "http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:8080/health": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

mean that the HTTP request has failed. For the readiness and liveness probe to work properly, this type of request must be successful.

To find out where the problem is, you need to get the pod IP address. Run:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
```

You should see an output similar to this:

```
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE                                       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
<my-pod-name>               1/1     Running   0          25d   10.92.3.4   <my-node-name>                             <none>           1/1
```

Take your IP and run:

```
kubectl exec -t <another_pod> -- curl -I <pod's cluster IP>
```

If you get a 200 response code, it means the endpoint is properly created and configured. Any other answer suggests there is a problem with your image.

See also:

- [this similar question](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/89898) (with solution) on github
- [very similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53067308/readiness-probe-failed-get-http-10-32-1-7180-setting-s-net-http-request-ca)
- [guide how to set up liveness and readiness probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)
- [this nice article](https://bleepcoder.com/kubernetes/595227484/sometime-liveness-readiness-probes-fail-because-of-net-http)

Comment: Hi @Mikołaj Głodziak - I am getting 200 response using kubectl exec. I have gone through other links that you have provided it suggests to use exec liveness probe instead of http liveness probe. However exec probe has its own downside as well. I am trying out exec probe currently. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Mikolaj, Any idea how we can enable exec liveness probe using OpenFaaS. I have tried to go through OpenFaaS documentation but couldn't spot it.

Comment: Take in to [this doc](https://docs.openfaas.com/reference/workloads/). You can enable httpProbe in the helm chart and implement /_/health as a HTTP endpoint.

Comment: Does it enable exec liveness probe? I have gone through other links that you have provided it suggests to use exec liveness probe instead of http liveness probe.

Comment: Exec probes are default. [reference](https://docs.openfaas.com/architecture/production/#configure-function-health-check-probes). If you want to switch from "exec" liveness and readiness probes to httpProbes then use `--set faasnetes.httpProbe=true`, this can only be used with `--set operator.create=false`. Read more [here](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/openfaas/openfaas/3.2.3)

Comment: cURL may not exist everywhere, `ping` might be a good alternative in that case instead of `curl -I`